# Trying to get property 'inv_nombre' of non-object - laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, angular

Tengo el Metodo de la imagen(Laravel) que deberia insertar los valores que se ingresan en un formulario hecho en angular a la base de datos, desde el front llega un objeto form con todos los atributos a guardar pero cuando clickeo el boton sale el mensaje Trying to get property 'inv_nombre' of non-object

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por que desde angular envio lo siguiente  public form = {
    inv_nombre : null,
    inv_apellPater : null,
    inv_apellMater: null,
    inv_cedula: null,
    inv_correo: null,
    inv_telefono: null,
    fk_ciu_codigo: null,
    fk_ent_codigo: null
  }  Entonces debo accesar a el como un array par poder entrar a cada atributo a no ser que me este equivocando. obvio los null se reemplazan por lo que ingresa por teclado

Comment: Por favor el código que completa tu pregunta agrégalo al cuerpo de la misma, pero en forma de texto, lo mismo con el que ya habías colocado

Comment: Hola @Cristianp1993, revisa que en el modelo investigador, tengas la propiedad de la sigueiente forma protected $fillable = [ 'inv_nombre ']